# Templated Stack Linked List

Tags: stack

I have written a templates stack linked list for an assignment I have to complete. When I run it, it prints out the first element, but then crashes. Any ideas on what could be going wrong? I have a feeling it might be the pop function, but its so basic, I'm not sure what is even wrong.

```
template<typename T>
struct StackNode
{
    T data;
StackNode* next;
StackNode(T t, StackNode* ptr);
~StackNode();
};

template <typename T>
StackNode<T>::StackNode(T t, StackNode* ptr = nullptr)
:data(t), next(ptr)
{
}

template <typename T>
StackNode<T>::~StackNode()
{
delete next;
}





template<typename T>
struct LinkedStack 
{

    LinkedStack();
    LinkedStack(const StackNode<T> &s);
    ~LinkedStack();
    bool isEmpty();
    void push(const T& t);
    void pop();
    T top();

    StackNode<T>* head;
    int numElements;
};

template <typename T>
LinkedStack<T>::LinkedStack()
    : head(nullptr), numElements(0)
{
}

template<typename T>
LinkedStack<T>::LinkedStack(const StackNode<T> &s)
    : head(nullptr), numElements(0)
{
    for (auto t = s.head; t; t = t->next)
        push(t->item);
}

template<class T>
LinkedStack<T>::~LinkedStack()
{
    while (!isEmpty())
    {
        pop();
    }
}


template<typename T>
bool LinkedStack<T>::isEmpty()
{
    if (numElements > 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

template<typename T>
void LinkedStack<T>::push(const T& t)
{
    head = new StackNode<T>(t, head);
    numElements++;
}

template<typename T>
void LinkedStack<T>::pop()
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        cout << "Stack is empty." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        StackNode<T>* oldnode = head;
        head = head->next;
        numElements--;
        delete oldnode;
    }
}

template<typename T>
T LinkedStack<T>::top()
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        cout << "Stack is empty..." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        return head->data;
    }
}




int main() 
{
    LinkedStack<string> x;
    x.push("Test");
    x.push("One");
    x.push("Two");
    x.push("Three");
    cout << "Now popping all elements of the stack:" << endl;

    while (x.isEmpty() == false)
    {
        cout << x.top() << endl;
        x.pop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you delete a node, you also delete the node it points to :

```
template <typename T>
StackNode<T>::~StackNode()
{
    delete next;
}
```

When you pop an item, you delete the whole linked list as the deletion propagate from a node to another. The segfault is raised after deleting the last node, your programs try to delete **nullptr**.

The delete statement in the **pop** function is enough. No need to delete Stacknode.next as you do not assign it with the **new** keyword

I've successfully runned your code after removing the problematic delete.